# SharePoint Mystery Order Column in Survey

Tags: survey-list, survey

I'm creating a Sharepoint 2013 (O365) Survey, when I go to test this it is pre-populated with a field called 'Order' which requires a numeric entry. I don't want this field, how do I remove it from the survey please? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

background reading: http://en.share-gate.com/blog/sharepoint-columns-site-columns-or-content-types

- Switch the Survey list to use ContentTypes (Settings -> Advanced)
- Open de Contenttype (in List Settings)
- Remove the Columns you do not want
  *this Survey List does some extra stuff, maybe it is better to Hide the Column*

Note: this is the List contenttype your are editting, you have to click up the ContentType tree to have changes applied to a broader scope.

```
-> Site Collection ContentType
   -> Site ContentType
      -> List ContentType
```

But.. it is Best Practice to create a New ContentType from an Existing one and make modifications in your own ContentType

Comment: Hi Danny, thanks but I don't seem to have the ability under Advanced to open the Content Type in List settings. I've tried many ways to get to this view but I'm not able to. When I open a Survey I still see the first entry as 'Order' with a field to enter on numbers :-(

Comment: Oh my, didn't realize this was one of Microsoft own creations... but.. I created a Survey on O365 and it does not have an Order column..